# Swift: Random delay only works first time? Random number func only executed once?

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit

Alright so I'm building a sprite kit game where I need to delay an enemy spawn func **repeatedly**.

I've managed to generate random `Double`s using this function:

```
func randomDelay()->Double {
        var randLower : UInt32 = 1
        var randUpper : UInt32 = 50
        var randDelayTime = arc4random_uniform(randUpper - randLower) + randLower
        var randDelayTimer = Double(randDelayTime) / 10
        //var randDelay = randDelayTimer * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        //var newTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(randDelay))

        println(randDelayTimer)

        return randDelayTimer
    }
```

I know this works because I printed `randDelayTimer` out several times and it does in fact generate random `Double`s.

Here is where I try to spawn my enemies after the random delay repeatedly:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(randomDelay())),
                SKAction.runBlock({self.spawnEnemy1()})))
```

This works, but only the first time it is run. Whatever random `Double` is generated by `randomDelay()` the FIRST TIME the sequence is cycled through is applied to every enemy that is spawned after that. For example if when the game is run, `randomDelay()` = 3.5, a 3.5 sec delay is repeated forever.

I know that `randomDelay()` is only being run that first time also because nothing is printed to the console after the first time.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following static method on `SKAction`:

```
class func waitForDuration(_ sec: NSTimeInterval,
                 withRange durationRange: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction
```

From the [`SKAction` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:withRange:):

> Each time the action is executed, the action computes a new random value for the duration. The duration may vary in either direction by up to half of the value of the durationRange parameter.

In your case, with a minimum duration of 1 second and a maximum duration of 50 seconds, you'd use:

```
// A mean wait of 25.5 seconds. The wait can vary by 24.5 seconds above and below the mean.
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(25.5, withRange: 49)
```

It's a little inconvenient to manually calculate the mean and range from the maximum and minimum waiting time, so you could use an extension on `SKAction` to do the work for you:

```
extension SKAction {
    static func waitForDuration(minimum min: NSTimeInterval, maximum max: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.waitForDuration((max + min) / 2, withRange: abs(max - min))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(minimum: 1, maximum: 50)
```

Comment: How would I use this? Can you provide an example of using this on an SKAction?

Comment: By changing the range calculation to `let range = abs(max - min)`, you can avoid conditionally swapping the values and, therefore, use constant arguments.

Comment: Good idea, I've updated my answer accordingly; looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, I think that did it. Is there a way to print out the delay when it is generated? Like print out the duration of the random delay when it occurs?

Comment: I was wondering that myself actually. I'm not aware of a way to; but perhaps some else does...